# graph editor -> how to "jump" to the row of my selected keyframes?

Tags: graph-editor

So i selected some keyframes of my mixamo animation in graph editor.

[image]

Now i want that the left panel jumps to the selected channels as the outliner does if you press dot. (opens hierarchy and selects the object)

How can i do that? is there a shortcut?

[image]

Comment: closest I know is 'numpad .' for  "frame selected" is supposed to do that.  Not working? (does have to be the numpad)

Comment: it works in the graph editor itself, but i meant the left column with the channels...i hoped it would "jump" to the selected ones

Comment: I thought that's what you meant and I thought it would do the jump.  as far as I know there's no other way.  There should be though.

Comment: i added a gif, hopefully it makes it more clear.

Comment: I think what you really want is to automatically synchronize the side bar with the graph, and according to devtalk that's broken.

Comment: that's really sad :(